# KVM guest not reaching externally (OVH, failover IPs)

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, mac-address, ovh

Both host and guest are running Fedora 26 server edition. Host is from OVH, guest is ISO from Fedora directly.

I've trimmed anything regarding TXRX and loopbacks for the sake of brevity.

```
Main IP a.a.a.17
Main IP Gateway a.a.a.254
Failover IP b.b.b.192
Failover MAC 20:00:00:10:5f:d7
```

Host ifconfig

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet a.a.a.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast a.a.a.255
        ether 70:54:d2:1a:9f:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfe500000-fe520000

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:3a:fb:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc00:ff:fe10:5fd7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:00:00:10:5f:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Guest ifconfig

```
ens3: flags=4163(UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST) 
        inet b.b.b.192  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast b.b.b.192
        ether 02:00:00:10:5f:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

KVM network setup

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='02:00:00:10:5f:d7'/>
  <source network='default' bridge='virbr0'/>
  <target dev='vnet0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Host brctl

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.000000000000       no
virbr0          8000.5254003afbf8       yes             virbr0-nic
                                                        vnet0
```

Guest arp -an

```
? (a.a.a.254) at (incomplete) on ens3
```

Currently, the guest cannot reach the internet. I've read and reread every article specific to OVH and even just general libvirt documentation, stumped at this point. This is my first time dealing with straight KVM instead of using a system like ESXi, but I deal with cli quite often. I appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: Is *b.b.b.192* the address *192.168.122.192/24*? You do not need to truncate private subnets, which makes is more difficult to understand your problem. But it is very likely that you have a routing issue. What is the output of `ip route` in your guest. Can you ping *192.168.122.1*?

Comment: `b.b.b.192` is not a private subnet. It's a failover IP from OVH, so it's a fully public IP address. I cannot ping the private subnet IP. I am trying to use the failover and not use DHCP at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual network `virbr0` is configured to use NAT for the virtual machines. What you want to achieve is to bridge the physical device `eth0` with e.g. `br0` and attach your VMs to this bridge.
The `eth0` would then be part of `br0` and you have to configure the IP address which is attached to `eth0` on `br0`. For more details please follow the steps [here](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Bridged_networking_.28aka_.22shared_physical_device.22.29).

Since you are running Fedora 26, you also should be able to make use of `macvtap` which is explained [here](http://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesDirect).

Comment: I appreciate the answer and will give this a shot.